# Create a shortcut to a batch file with args

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch-file

I need to create a shortcut to a batchfile say start.bat, with  some arguments.

Can I do it like `"D:\Jboss\start.bat" arg1 arg2`

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?

Answer (score 2):

First, create a shortcut by right clicking on the `start.bat` and select `Send To - Desktop (create shortcut)`

Right click on the shortcut on the desktop and show its Properties. In the Shortcut tab, you will be able to append arguments to the Target path. [This figure demonstrates how it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7D94.png)